# C# Hyper-V Manager side menu-like?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I was wondering what type of side menu Microsoft used in their Hyper-V Manager (or mmc as well) and wanted to ask you If there is such control in C# (Winform / wpf) and what is the name of it?

I was trying to play with TreeView but it sucked in many ways, e.g. I was not able to "unfocus" selected node and so on.

Hope you are all doing well during this time.

Thank you!

[hyper-v manager side menu screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG8P7.png)

Comment: Those are just a bunch of Buttons, *sliding* Panels and a couple of MenuButtons. Search for DirectUI -- [What is the fact of DirectUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5850466/7444103) --> [Windows.UI.Xaml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml?view=winrt-19041)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a 3rd party library having Accordion Control

Ex: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114553/controls-and-libraries/navigation-controls/accordion-control

Or make one for yourselves using WPF/WinForms Custom Control.

Comment: I was searching for some native solution. Let's see If someone is has better idea. If not I will create a custom control.

Comment: Native solution is to create a Custom Control yourselves. I dont remember MS releasing an accordion control.

Comment: So custom control it is. Thank you.